# Can't get pecl memcached to build 32 bit version for XAMPP on mac os x Snow leopard

Tags: php, apache, build, memcached, pecl

I'm attempting to install the PHP pecl memcache extension on my Mac for my local development environment, and it will only install the 64 bit version which is not compatible with 32 bit php from XAMPP.

These are the steps I've taken:

```
cd /tmp/
c-66-31-208-39:/tmp casey$ pecl download memcache-2.2.5
c-66-31-208-39:/tmp casey$ tar xzf memcache-2.2.5.tgz
c-66-31-208-39:/tmp casey$ cd memcache-2.5.5

c-66-31-208-39:memcache-2.2.5 casey$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize-5.3.1 MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64'

c-66-31-208-39:memcache-2.2.5 casey$ ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config-5.3.1

c-66-31-208-39:memcache-2.2.5 casey$ make

c-66-31-208-39:memcache-2.2.5 casey$ sudo make install
```

After all of that completes successfully, I run:

```
c-66-31-208-39:memcache-2.2.5 casey$ file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

And it's the 64 bit version? I'm not an expert on building software from source, can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`configure` line needs `CFLAGS` as well.

something like:

```
CFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' CCFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure ...rest of your configure args...
```

You might want the `-O3` and `-fno-common` from the lines above in there as well.